# Canvas.create_image Not Showing? Python 3.6

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm using Python 3.6 And Experimenting With `canvas.create_image()`.
In The Code Below I Created A Canvas Then An Image, But When I Run The
Script I Got No Image, Just A Plain Canvas.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

one = PhotoImage(r"img1")
two = PhotoImage(r"img2")

canvas = Canvas(root, bg='white')
canvas.pack()

bgim = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=one, anchor='nw')


mainloop()
```

I Made Sure The Photo Wasn't The Problem, As I Used Other Images And It Didn't Work.
Hope To Get Some Help, Thanks :)

Comment: You can't create an image from a string. What do you think `PhotoImage(r"img1")` is going to do?

Comment: @BryanOakley I put the image as "img1" to hide the real file its fine